# Paragraph spacing that does not affect the content section

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm writing my thesis, and I'd like to have a blank space between the paragraphs in the chapters, so I used the following code

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

However, this command does also affect the Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables sections, that instead I'd like with no spacing between the lines. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: best is to use a class that is designed for vertically spaced paragraphs, but failing that using the `parskip` package instead of setting `\parskip` directly will remove some of the bad effects.

Comment: Said that, you can also change the `\parskip` only for some parts of text, eg.g.:  in `\parskip3em  aaa \par bbb \par {\parskip0pt ccc\par ddd\par} eee\par fff`. You can apply a 0pt paragraph skip only to the table of contents in same way.